# Approximate function with fixed amount of linear segments

Tags: algorithms, approximation

I want to approximate a known, continuous function $f(x)$ within in a given interval $[a, b]$ by linear segments, defined by their start/end points. The amount $N$ of points is given, but they don't have to be equidistant (otherwise, this problem would be trivial).

I assume this is a pretty common problem, but I can't find much about it online. Is there any common algorithm for this?

---

Here is a quick example sketch of what I mean, with $N = 14$.
[image]

Comment: https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/Piecewise_linear_approximation

Comment: A term to search is "piecewise linear approximation". I gave a quick example link above. You can obviously approximate quite easily by just partitioning the curve into segments, but if you want an efficient linear approximation you should know where it's "curving" more in order to use smaller segments there

Comment: @jmb The problem appears underspecified as stated. Presumably you have an error criterion in mind that applies to the N segments, e.g. the maximum relative error of the linear approximation should be roughly equal in each segment (for some definition of roughly)?

Comment: @jmb A guess: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.02975) maybe close to what you want: D Berjon, et.al., "Optimal Piecewise Linear Function Approximation
for GPU-based Applications", ArXiv:1510.02975: *We propose a novel, fast, and practical method to evaluate
any continuous mathematical function within a known interval.
Our contributions include, based on error equalization, a nearly
optimal design of two types of piecewise linear approximations
(linear interpolant and orthogonal projection) in the $L_2$ norm
under the constraint of a large budget of evaluation subintervals
$N$.*